# G Suite Drive API: Why can't I get the permissions of a specific file?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-workspace

I am consuming data from the G Suite Drive API and I am getting the following error:

```
[2020-05-09 05:42:33,626: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<FILE_ID>/permissions?fields=%2A&alt=json
[2020-05-09 05:42:34,089: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Encountered 403 Forbidden with reason "insufficientFilePermissions"
[2020-05-09 05:42:34,089: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] drive#permission: HTTP error (code 403): The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.
```

The file causing the trouble is a JPEG. I have both the file ID and the file name.

The situation is as follows:

- When looking for the file using the [Drive Files API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) and providing the file ID a 200 HTTP response is returned.
- When looking for the file permissions using the [Drive Permissions API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list), a 403 HTTP error is raised.
- When looking for the file using the Drive search bar and providing the file name, nothing is found.

Can anyone shed light on this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you the owner / editor or viewer of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If your permissions allow you to use [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) but not [Permissions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list),  you have only View Access to a file

You need to be an editor or owner to use `Permissions:list`

Answer (score 0):

@ziganotschka's answer is correct for Drive API v3, but it's actually possible to retrieve permissions if you only have read access using the older version of Google's API (v2).

This API is less efficient by default though, so recommend passing in `fields` to it to overcome this (it does accept it as a parameter, even though it's not clearly documented on [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/list)).

Answer (score -1):

> 403 Forbidden with reason "insufficientFilePermissions"

Means that you dont have permission to do what you are trying to do

[permissions.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/get) requires that the user who is preforming the action has authenticated with one of the following scopes

[image]

If you change the scopes in your application remember that you need to run the application again so that it requests consent of the user in order to gain the new consent.

Comment: @DalmTo Please, correct me if I am wrong, but both, Files and Permissions API have some scopes in common. For instance, I am using in the two API calls the same scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly, which in theory is valid. If so, why I am getting a 200 response in one case and a 403 in the other one. Maybe this is not related to the scopes.

Comment: Read only will only allow you to read data not change it if you want to change it then your going to need drive.file permission.